# MySQL python-telegram-bot При выводе в боте (имя) перемещается в вторую колонку

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot

```
import telebot
import mysql.connector

bot = telebot.TeleBot("")


db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="root",
  database="youtube"
)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "доступ к боту")
    mycursor = db.cursor()

    sql = 'SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = %s'
    users_id = message.from_user.id
    var = (users_id,)
    mycursor.execute(sql, var)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    db.commit()
    for x in myresult:
        my_str = 'имя:\t\n фамилия:\t'.join(x)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, my_str, parse_mode='Markdown')
    ####результат в телеграме                                                                        
  Евгений имя: 
 фамилия: попов

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Уберите /n в тексте и попробуйте заново

Comment: print(“Junaid \n Effendi”) 
Output:

Junaid 
Effendi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for row in myresult:
    firstname = row[0]
    lastname = row[1]

    #my_str = 'имя:\t\n фамилия:\t'.join(x)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ИМЯ:\t" + str(firstname) + "\nФамилия:" + lastname)
```